# Windows 7 - Multiple keyboards

Tags: windows-7, audio, keyboard

I am using windows 7 on my desktop. I recently bought a new keyboard - the [Microsoft Sidewinder x4](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/sidewinder-x4-keyboard). I was trying to figure out why my volume buttons were not working and I stumbled upon something strange. Windows seems to think that I have 3 keyboards connected although I only have one keyboard connected via USB. How can I tell Windows that there is only 1 keyboard?

[image: a]

**The Device Manager is also showing 3 keyboards.**

[image: b]

I unplugged my keyboard and 2 of the 3 disappeared, the device manager only showed 1 keyboard now. But there was no other keyboard. It seems that the sidewinder keyboard is recognized as two separate one, I installed a driver for my keyboard (NOT just now). As soon as I scan for hardware changes the uninstalled ones pop back up.

GIF

[image]

Comment: Does the same issue persist in Device Manager

Comment: @DaveRook yes it does

Comment: In lack of better explanation, I would say you got 3 for 1.

Comment: @Sammy what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: It means you payed for one keyboard and got two for free. It's a joke, in case you didn't catch that. Although it should really be four for one, since it's called "X4". That's one special keyboard you got there. Any idea why it's called "X4"?

Comment: so that they can sell a x6 version. jk I do not know.

Comment: You can try reinstalling it. Right click on the ones called "HID Keybaord Device" in Device Manager, and click Uninstall. So that only "Microsoft SideWinder X4" is left in the list. If this doesn't solve it, I would personally let it be. Or you could contact the place where you bought it or contact Microsoft and ask them what this is. Because this is not normal. I've never seen three entries for one keyboard. It's a good thing it's a Microsoft product, right? Because they make Windows too, right? So it should work...

Comment: weird thing is that it works just fine on my linux partition.

Comment: @Sammy If I uninstall all but the x4 keyboard and then scan for hardware changes they pop back up.

Comment: It seems I cannot uninstall any keyboard, they just pop back up

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop computer? If it's a laptop then that would explain why you have 1 keyboard left after unplugging your Microsoft keyboard. But it does not explain why your Microsoft keybaord has two entries. It's as if it's built around two pieces of a keyboard and then glued together... I don't know.

Comment: I am using a desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some USB devices are made up of several subdevices. Your keyboard is likely one of them. This is perfectly normal.

To illustrate, here's a screenshot of my configuration, consisting of one keyboard and one mouse (Logitech G700):
[image: Device Manager illustrating multiple subdevices]

Answer (score 1):

1:  Make sure it has the latest drivers installed, there are drivers and programs listed for download in your link.  I bet those would fix the problem.

2:  I would try a different USB bus.  Usually the front USB and back USB ports on most desktops are on different chips, perhaps trying the other chip might "reset" it or something.

3:  Obviously a bit extreme, but a re-install of the system would definitely help narrow down or fix the problem.  (It's very easy to re-install in some cases, not sure if your situation is one of them)

Comment: re-installing is getting solving the problem by getting rid of the problem. I will try number 2.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel B's answer is probably correct (your keyboard is acting as multiple devices). The reason why keyboards will do that is because the designers of USB decided that a USB keyboard should only be able to [send 6 simultaneous regular keys + 4 modifier keys](http://deskthority.net/wiki/Rollover,_blocking_and_ghosting#Interface-limited_NKRO) (shift, control, etc):

> The USB Human Interface Device (HID) protocol fully supports N-key rollover. However, the compatibility version of HID that all present systems implement limits USB keyboards to reporting a mere six regular keys together with four modifiers. Additional keys pressed beyond the limit will generally cause some of the other keys to be dropped.
>
> Many USB keyboards implement workarounds to bypass this limit; the most common trick is to simulate multiple endpoints, e.g. the keyboard pretends to be a USB hub with several keyboards attached. When more than six keys are pressed simultaneously, the keyboard controller simulates up to six keys coming from one of its virtual keyboards, and the rest coming from its other virtual keyboards.